# Why does importing some SciPy modules take so long on Windows?

Tags: python, performance, scipy

On some of my otherwise-relatively-fast Windows machines, importing SciPy modules like `scipy.signal` takes an absurdly long time (over a second).

And I can't simply Ctrl-C in the middle to see what's going on, thanks to good old SciPy overriding the stack trace:

```
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFBD9AFD37F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFBDBE213D2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFBDC8C54E4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

This doesn't happen on all my machines, though. What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a very frustrating issue for me to track down, so I'm posting the solution here.

I ended up using Visual Studio's debugger to break into the program and see what it's doing.

It turns out there are 2 orthogonal factors that contribute to this:

- For reasons beyond my comprehension, some package(s) (I'm looking at `scikits.odes` here) have `__init__.py`'s that have this line:

  ```
  __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  ```

  For reasons beyond my comprehension, once `scikits.odes` is imported (which SciPy does for some bizarre reason), this line ends up running, loading an ungodly number of packages from your installation (seemingly, most if not all of them). This grows slower the bigger your installation.

  The solution to this problem is to either uninstall this offending package, or if you really need it, to comment out this line (or do something equivalent) and hope it doesn't get offended.
- You haven't compiled your `.py` files to `.pyc` (run `python -m compileall .` inside your Python installation directory). This *actually helps for a lot of packages*. (I was skeptical at first.)

Fixing both of these issues reduced my import time to around 0.3 seconds, which seems normal.

Comment: *"once `scikits.odes` is imported (which SciPy does for some bizarre reason)"*  Are you saying scipy imports `scikits.odes`?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: [Yes, that's what I'm saying.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/12b69927915de8401e2db36eac07f91b3aeead9f/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L15) Go figure.

Comment: That code tries to import `scikits.umfpack`.  Does that also somehow trigger an import of `scikits.odes`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Er, I think I found the wrong line in the source code. It's definitely loading for some reason. Not exactly sure why. Have you tried this on your end?

Comment: There is history behind the `scikits` namespace that I don't know very well.  I know the early attempt to implement the "scikits" as namespace packages caused problems, which is why projects like scikit-learn and scikit-image eventually dropped the `scikit` namespace, and changed their package names to `sklearn` and `skimage`, respectively.  That use of `__import__(...)` that you show in your answer is part of how python implements namespace packages.  (Having heard about the problems, I learned to avoid them, and never looked into the details of their implementation.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: So what's happening is `import scikits.umfpack as umfpack` is invoking `scikits\__init__.py` which has the line `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` which is in turn importing a *ton* of things (though apparently `odes` is not one of them). Strictly speaking, I guess this is not `scikits.odes`, because `odes` is a subfolder of `scikits`. But `scikits.odes` is what installed this `__init__.py` file in the first place, and when I remove it this file gets removed too. So yes, the blame gets split across `SciPy` and `scikits`.